# Magnetic field energy transfer between poles

Tags: electromagnetism

Is there an actual transfer of energy between the poles of a permanent magnet via the magnetic field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Poynting's paper from 1884](http://rstl.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/175/343.full.pdf+html), no.

Answer (score 0):

Under the influence of a second magnet or a magnetizable body the orientation of the magnetic dipoles of the involved subatomic particles of your magnet get oriented slightly different from their orientation in the case without the second body. During the approach and during the removing of the second body the process of realignment is accompanied by energy transfer on the atomic level.